# Removing location specific information after a specific ":" character that can occur in any cell, multiple times, in a cell range of 1-1416

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a report and want to exclude any location specific information from the data. These usually appear after a colon, and can occur randomly within the same cell. I've included an example of this:

Community Pages, /contact-sales, Form Tracking | form (contactUs-form) | Community, Community Pages, Sub Navigation | Click | **Find a Location:Bay Area:/new-homes-bay-area/**, Region Pages, Map List | Click | KB-Community Map:View Community:Bay Area::/new-homes-bay-area, Community Pages, Floor Plan Pages, /contact-sales, Form Tracking | form (contactUs-form) | Area, Community Pages, /contact-sales, Form Tracking | form (contactUs-form) | Region, Form Tracking | form (contactUs-form) | Community, Form Tracking | form (contactUs-form) | FirstName (change), Form Tracking | form (contactUs-form) | LastName (change), Form Tracking | form (contactUs-form) | Phone (change), Form Tracking | form (contactUs-form) | Email (change), Form Tracking | form (contactUs-form) | Phone (change), Form Tracking | form (contactUs-form) | userComments (change), Form Tracking | form (contactUs-form) | contactUs-form (submit), Community Pages, Left Rail Link | Click | Get Community Updates:Link:/new-homes-bay-area/, /contact-sales, Body Link | Click | Contact Us-Contact Sales:Submit, Data Storage | Virtual Pageviews | /contact-sales/thank-you, /contact-sales/thank-you

This is a similar example, but not location specific. 
Please execute the following instructions to all rows they apply to:
Following the pattern: Category | Action | Label

1. When you see a Label with a colon, remove any specific information that follows the colon (such as location specific) until next comma
   Note: There are a lot of variations of labels with the colon, so please use the same logic for all.
   Example #1

**From this:** Community Pages, Data Storage | Micro Conversions | Get Community Updates, My KB | Click | Register with Facebook:/my-kb-new, /MyKb-New

**To this:** Community Pages, Micro Conversions | Get Community Updates, My KB | Click | Register with Facebook, /MyKb-New

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have told us what you are trying to do, but forgot to mention what problem is stopping you from doing it.

Comment: You could probably split the string into an array using `|` as your delimiter. Then check each element to see if it contains your colon.

Comment: I can't seem to find a pattern that works for every case. Out of 1416 rows, only 483 of them have a frequency > 1. I have never done anything this complex. Do I use an array or collection? And within that I would think a For Loop? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs,

Events in the path are comma delimited, within each event, there is a category, action, and label. Each is separated with "|"

Comment: @K.W Updated my answer

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `Split()` and `Join()` functions on this one.

1. Split your array by your delimiter, in this case `,`
2. Iterate through each element, searching for your data by using `InStr()` to see if it contains a colon

   - If the data contains a colon, split it
   - If the data does not contain a colon, add it to your new array as-is
3. Join the array back into a string

---

```
Sub Test()

    'Run this code. This Sub will call stripData

    Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    For i = 1 To 1416   'This was the range you specified in your title
        ws.Cells(i, 1) = stripData(ws.Cells(i, 1))
    Next

End Sub

Function stripData(sRawData As String) As String

    Dim sRawArr$(), sNewArr$(), sNewData$, i&

    sRawArr = Split(sRawData, ",")
    ReDim sNewArr(UBound(sRawArr))

    For i = 0 To UBound(sRawArr)
        If InStr(1, sRawArr(i), ":") = 0 Then
            sNewArr(i) = Trim(sRawArr(i))
        Else
            sNewArr(i) = Trim(Split(sRawArr(i), ":")(0))
        End If
    Next

    stripData = Join(sNewArr, ", ")

End Function
```